# What is the best way to secure connections from google-dataflow to on-premise postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a data flow job reads from pub/sub and writes into elasticsearch and postgresql.

Postgresql is located behind the firewall of the company. In order data-flow to access postgresql db we have to set permissions on firewall. But the problem is we don't have data-flow workers IP addresses and we don't want to permit all incoming locations to postgresql.

What is the best way to secure writes from data-flow to postgresql?

Comment: You could probably use the Dataflow `network` parameter i.e. create a GCE network and specify that in your pipelines. I've not tried it, but might work. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#Options

Comment: @GrahamPolley I cloudn't try it yet but I think it won't work. When I put workers into a GCE ( private network ) they will be in same network that is ok. But they are still in a different network than postgresql db. So I don't know these workers external IP addresses or address ranges to write rules on postgresql.

Currently instead of writing a PG outside of google; I created a PG instance on google query and use query-proxy to access the DB.